# Powershell script to download file with current date as filename from Azure blob - Download log file and Remove the Downloaded content from blob

Tags: azure, powershell

I have PowerShell script which downloads the file with current date as filename from Azure blob. But How to get the log file of the process and how to remove the file which is downloaded from Azure blob through script. Could someone help me in this, Please.

Example.

```
app_09102021.txt
app_10102021.txt
app_11102021.txt
```

Below is the script.

```
$container_name = '$XXX'
$destination_path = 'D:\test'
$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext $ZZZZ -StorageAccountKey $CCVCVCVCV
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$Listblobs = 'app_{0:ddMMyyyy}.txt' -f (Get-Date)
# Just download that blob
Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name -Blob $Listblobs -Destination $destination_path
```

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT Thanks a lot, it works in awesome way. Tones of Thanks. Really helpfull, and it strucks my mind several days, Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment to download the blobs and delete by using below `cmd` and its successfully downloaded and got removed from Azure as well .

```
$container_name = 'testaj'
$destination_path = 'C:\Users\Desktop\test'
$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext 'accountname' -StorageAccountKey 'accountkeyrA=='
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$Listblobs ='app_{0:ddMMyyyy}.txt' -f (Get-Date)

$blob = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name -Blob $Listblobs -Destination $destination_path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($blob  -ne $Null)
{
Write-Host ("The File $Listblobs has been downloaded to $destination_path")
Write-Host ("Proceeding to delete the downloaded file from $container_name in Azure!!!")

Remove-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Blob $Listblobs -Context $Ctx
Write-Host ("deleted file from $Listblobs in Azure!!!") 
}
else{
write-Host ("The file does not exit")
}
```

Here is the Output for downloaded and deleted file from blob:
[image]

If the file got deleted then it will be something like below:
[image]

For more information please refer this MS DOC: [Monitoring Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage?tabs=azure-portal)

**UPDATE:**

> I am looking for the solution to search & match the date with today's
> date in filename, not sorting by last modified date/time.

Tried with the below code to download all the blobs with todays date for e.g abc_04012022,app_04012022 and delete them from Azure

**PS Script** :-

```
$container_name = 'test'
$destination_path = 'C:\Users\Desktop\test'
$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext 'accountname' -StorageAccountKey 'accountkey=='
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$latestBlob = Get-Date -UFormat '%d%m%Y'

$bloblist = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $Ctx |select -Property Name

foreach($item in $bloblist){
            
            if($item.Name -match $latestBlob){
                    Write-Output "Here is the blobs"
                    $blob = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $Ctx -Container $container_name -Blob $item.Name -Destination $destination_path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    if($blob -ne $Null)
                    {
                        Write-Output ("The File $item.Name has been downloaded to $destination_path")
                        Write-Output ("Proceeding to delete the downloaded file from $container_name in Azure!!!")
                        
                        Remove-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Blob $item.Name -Context $Ctx

                         Write-Output ("deleted file from $item.Name in Azure!!!")
                    }
                    else{
                        write-Output ("The file does not exit")
                     }
            }
}
```

Screenshot for reference:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks lot @AjayKumarGose-MT , I am also looking for solution to download data from the blob which matches today's(current) date with filename irrespective of the letters before it. For example file in blob name is 'cqb01012022.txt; abc_01012022.txt; xyz01012022.txt'...the script should download all these three files matching with today's date. Looking for help.

Comment: Np @GopiArumugam , Please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777851/is-it-possible-to-list-azure-blobs-where-last-modified-date-some-date) 2nd solution .

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT, I am looking for the solution to search & match the date with today's date in filename, not sorting by last modified date/time. Will be great full for your help in this.

Comment: Hello @GopiArumugam , I have update the answer in UPDATE section. Could you please refer this. Thank you:)

Comment: Thanks a lot @AjayKumarGhose-MT, It works in awesome way. Tones of Thanks. No words to express my happiness.

Comment: You are welcome @GopiArumugam , HTH.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem